# I need to to know whether the Bluetooth is on/off regardless of the device

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

So I am trying to check whether the Bluetooth is on or off on the iOS device when this segment is running on my iPad Air it prints `Bluetooth Status: Turned On` or `Bluetooth Status: Turned Off` when I turn the Bluetooth on/off. But when I run this on the iPad 2 it prints `Bluetooth Status: Not Supported`.

```
fileprivate var bluetoothPeripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?

override init() {
    super.init()
    let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:0]
    bluetoothPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
}

extension PrintersMonitor: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager){
    var statusMessage = ""

    switch peripheral.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Turned On"
    case .poweredOff:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Turned Off"
    case .resetting:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Resetting"
    case .unauthorized:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Not Authorized"
    case .unsupported:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Not Supported"
        bluetoothPeripheralManager = nil
    default:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Unknown"
    }

    log(statusMessage)

    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn{
        if state != .searching{
            resume()
        }
    }else if peripheral.state == .poweredOff{
        pause(isPrinting: false)
    }
}
```

}

Is there something missing from my side!
I need to to know whether the Bluetooth is on/off regardless of the device!

Answer (score 0):

The iPad 2 does not support BLE, which is the Bluetooth that is exposed by Core Bluetooth. This is why you get a status of "not supported".

There are no APIs that provide the power status of legacy Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks first, But I saw some Apps on the iPad 2 that can detect the BT status! like Square Register App!